# Type class pattern in Scala doesn't consider inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, scala, implicit, typeclass

I am designing an API using type classes in some cases however I have encountered a problem with implicit resolution.  As shown below, if there is an implicit object for type A but an object of type `B extends A` is passed to the method, then an implicit object cannot be found.  Is there a way to make this work or do callers have to put implicit objects into scope for each subclass?

Here is an example:

```
class A
class B extends A

class T[+X]

object T {
  implicit object TA extends T[A]
}

def call[X:T](x:X) = println(x)

// compiles
call(new A)
// doesn't compile
call(new B)

var a = new A
// compiles
call(a)

a = new B
// compiles
call(a)

val b = new B
// doesn't compile
call(b)
```

This fails to compile with the following output:

```
/private/tmp/tc.scala:16: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type this.T[this.B]
call(new B)
    ^
/private/tmp/tc.scala:28: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type this.T[this.B]
call(b)
```

Comment: I also tried changing the definition of call to: 

   def call[X,X2 <: X](x:X2)(implicit x2:T[X]) = println(x)

And that did not help

Answer (score 8):

The call `call(new B)` means `call[B](new B)(tB)` such that tb is of type T[B] or subclass of it. (A method that expects argument of type T can only expect T or subclass of T, e.g., `def foo(s: String)` cannot be called with argument of type `Any`). T[A] is not a subtype of T[B]

To fix, you can change T to be defined `T[-X]`. This means that the compiler will consider T[A] to be a subtype of T[B]

Comment: Problem is, even if you also define `implicit object TB extends T[B]`, `implicitly[T[B]] == T.TA`. http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2509

Comment: sounds reasonable, because TA is then more specific than TB and TA is-a TB so should be usable where T[B] is. if you want the implicit to match the type exactly, define T as T[X]

Answer (score 4):

The following works fine:

```
scala> def call[X](x: X)(implicit evidence: T[X]<:<T[X])  = println(x)
call: [X](x: X)(implicit evidence: <:<[T[X],T[X]])Unit

scala> call(new A)
line0$object$$iw$$iw$A@1d869b2

scala> call(new B)
line2$object$$iw$$iw$B@b3a5d1

scala> val b = new B
b: B = B@30e4a7

scala> call(b)
line2$object$$iw$$iw$B@30e4a7
```

In your case compilation fails, because `def call[X:T](x:X) = println(x)` is treated as `call: [X](x: X)(implicit evidence$1: T[X])Unit`. In order to pass the subtype, you may use generalized type constraints.

Comment: Is there a way to actually get evidence$1?  For example suppose T was a function and x was the parameter.  I cannot call evidence(x)

Comment: Why you cannot? You can call it by name `evidence$1`, like any other [implicit] parameter.

Comment: If you have several type parameters on the method, there will be evidence$1, evidence$2 etc: `[X,Z](x: X)(implicit evidence$1: T[X],implicit evidence$2: T[Z])Unit`

Comment: My question did not quite capture my needs.  I loved learning this tip but my actual needs turned out to be:  <code>trait T[X] extends Function1[X,Boolean]</code>.  and call is: <code>def call[X](x:X)(implicit x2:T[X]) = x2(x)</code>.  Turned out using T[-X] worked for me.  Cool to learn about the <:< though.

Comment: `def foo[A: M] = { val ma = implicitly[M[A]; ... }`

Comment: @jesse-eichar If T[-X] worked out for you, why not accept the answer I provided?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
object T {
  implicit def TA[X <: A] = new T[X]
}

import T._
```

or simply:

```
implicit def TA[X <: A] = new T[X]
```