# How can I combine the typeclass pattern with subtyping?

Tags: scala, typeclass, variance

Suppose I'm using the typeclass pattern in Scala.  Here's how I make a class C
part of the typeclass Foo:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_26).

scala> trait Foo[T] { def foo(t: T) }
defined trait Foo

scala> def foo[T : Foo](t: T) { implicitly[Foo[T]].foo(t) }
foo: [T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: Foo[T])Unit

scala> class C
defined class C

scala> foo(new C)
<console>:11: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Foo[C]
       foo(new C)
          ^

scala> implicit object FooC extends Foo[C] { override def foo(c: C) { println("it's a C!") } }
defined module FooC

scala> foo(new C)
it's a C!
```

So far so good.  But suppose I have a subclass D of C, and I want instances of D to be "in" the typeclass too:

```
scala> class D extends C
defined class D

scala> foo(new D)
<console>:13: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Foo[D]
       foo(new D)
          ^
```

Doh!  How do I make this work without having to explicitly provide a typeclass instance for D?

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869991/type-class-pattern-in-scala-doesnt-consider-inheritance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are different possible solutions for this, depending on whether I want to fix the problem *only for C*, or whether I want to fix the problem *for the entire typeclass*.

For C only, instead of `implicit object FooC ...` we say:

```
implicit def CIsFoo[T <: C]: Foo[T] =
  new Foo[T] { override def foo(t: T) { println("it's a C!") } }
```

To fix all of Foo, make it contravariant:

```
trait Foo[-T] { def foo(t: T) }
```

Or if for some reason you can't or don't want to do that, you can replace `def foo...` with:

```
def foo[T](t: T)(implicit foo: Foo[_ >: T]) =
  foo.foo(t)
```

(Thanks to #scala denizens Daniel Sobral and Stefan Zeiger for their help.)

**UPDATED** Sep 20 2011 to include the "make Foo contravariant" solution, which I missed

Comment: There's another question lurking here...  What if I want D to be treated slightly differently than T, *but* share some common code!

Comment: @jsuereth Nothing prevents you from declaring an `implicit object FooD` for `D` as you did for `C`, and call methods from `FooC` in `FooD`.

Comment: Actually you should try it.  'Conflicting implicit imports' unless you muck with priorities.   The full solution looks pretty boiler-platey and can be frustrating to muck with.