# Why doesn't scala compiler infer type parameter from superclass?

Tags: scala

I want to understand why the scala compiler cannot infer a type parameter passed to a superclass so that I can come up with a workaround. Workaround suggestions are also very welcome! Here's a contrived example of what I'm stuck on (comments in the code explaining issues):

Code is also in a [scala fiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/bGtDio1/2).

```
/** A Svc is a function that responds to requests
  * @tparam Req[_] a request ADT whose instances specify their response type
  */
trait Svc[Req[_]] {
  def apply[Resp](req: Req[Resp]): Resp
}

/** Service request ADT */
sealed trait MyReq[_]
// two requests have the same response type of String (i.e. MyReq[String]):
case class GetString(id: String) extends MyReq[String]
case class GetAltString(id: String) extends MyReq[String]
// this one is the only MyReq[Int]
case class GetInt(id: String) extends MyReq[Int]

/** Type class for marshalling a response for a concrete request type.
  * This lets us handle marshalling differently for different requests
  * that have the same response type (such as GetString and GetAltString above).
  *
  * @tparam ReqImpl concrete MyReq type. This is required to enforce unique marshaller
  * per request when there are mutliple request types with the same response type.
  */
trait ReqMarshaller[ReqImpl <: MyReq[Resp], Resp] {
  def marshal(r: Resp): String
}

class MySvc extends Svc[MyReq] {
  // this apply function compiles and works just fine.
  override def apply[Resp](req: MyReq[Resp]): Resp = req match {
    case GetString(id) => id
    case GetAltString(id) => id + id
    case GetInt(id) => id.length
  }

  // This is the problem. I want to specify the request is a subclass so
  // we get the specific marshaller for the request type and avoid
  // ambiguous implicit errors.
  // However, the Resp type parameter is always inferred as Nothing
  // instead of the correct response type.
  def marshal[ReqImpl <: MyReq[Resp], Resp](req: ReqImpl)(
    implicit
    marshaller: ReqMarshaller[ReqImpl, Resp]
  ): String = marshaller.marshal(apply(req))

  // this method is just here to show that it won't work as a solution
  // because it doesn't work when there are multiple request types with
  // the same response type (causes ambiguous implicits errors)
  def marshalGeneric[Resp](req: MyReq[Resp])(
    implicit
    marshaller: ReqMarshaller[_ <: MyReq[Resp], Resp]
  ): String = marshaller.marshal(apply(req))
}

implicit val getIntMarshaller: ReqMarshaller[GetInt, Int] = new ReqMarshaller[GetInt, Int] {
  def marshal(i: Int): String = (i * i).toString
}

implicit val getStrMarshaller: ReqMarshaller[GetString, String] = new ReqMarshaller[GetString, String] {
  def marshal(s: String): String = s
}

implicit val getAltStrMarshaller: ReqMarshaller[GetAltString, String] = new ReqMarshaller[GetAltString, String] {
  def marshal(s: String): String = s + s
}

val svc = new MySvc

val myLength = svc(GetInt("me")) // 2
println(s"myLength: $myLength")

svc.marshalGeneric(GetInt("me")) // compiles and works
//svc.marshal(GetInt("me")) // fails to compile due to infering Resp type as Nothing
//svc.marshalGeneric(GetAltString("me")) // fails to compile because of ambiguous implicits
```

Comment: could you make a scastie?

Comment: @nafg thanks for the suggestion. I made a scala fiddle instead: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/bGtDio1/0

Comment: this might help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682824/how-can-i-combine-the-typeclass-pattern-with-subtyping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that Scala is trying to infer both `ReqImpl` and `Resp` type parameters at once instead of inferring `ReqImpl` first and getting `Resp` from that. Since `Resp` doesn't actually appear in the parameter list, it's inferred to `Nothing` and then Scala notices type bounds are violated. A workaround (I don't remember where I saw it first) is to give an equivalent type to `req` but one which depends on `Resp` explicitly:

```
def marshal[ReqImpl <: MyReq[Resp], Resp](req: ReqImpl with MyReq[Resp])(
  implicit marshaller: ReqMarshaller[ReqImpl, Resp]
): String = marshaller.marshal(apply(req))
```

`svc.marshal(GetInt("me"))` now compiles.

Comment: This solves the compiler inferring the `Resp` type to be `Nothing` - but I'm still getting compiler error for ambiguous implicits for `svc.marshalGeneric(GetAltString("me"))`. But, you have answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: For `marshalGeneric(GetAltString("me"))` you simply do have ambiguous implicits: both `getStrMarshaller` and `getAltStrMarshaller` are suitable. Do you want it to do something different from the fixed `marshal`?

Comment: Of course you are right. I forgot to change the `marshalGeneric(GetAltString("me"))` back to `marshal(GetAltString("me"))`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to capture the relationship between Type parameter of `Req` and type param of your `apply` function in your Svc trait. And then you can modify the rest of things accordingly.

```
trait Svc[Req[_ <: XX], XX] {
  def apply[Resp <: XX](req: Req[Resp]): Resp
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to explicitly mention your `ReqImpl` is a parametrised type ([Type infered to Nothing in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888136/type-infered-to-nothing-in-scala)). In your case it will look like this:

```
def marshal[ReqImpl[Resp] <: MyReq[Resp], Resp](req: ReqImpl[Resp])(
  implicit
  marshaller: ReqMarshaller[ReqImpl[Resp], Resp]
): String = marshaller.marshal(apply(req))
```

But there are two problems with this approach:

(1) In `svc.marshal(GetInt("me"))` Scala will infer the type of `RepImpl` as `MyReq[Int]`, which kind of make sense, but `ReqMarshaller[GetInt, Int]` won't match. So you need to define it as:

```
implicit val getIntMarshaller = new ReqMarshaller[MyReq[Int], Int] {
  def marshal(i: Int): String = (i * i).toString
}
```

(2) Now you immediately have another problem, you can't define two `ReqMarshaller[MyReq[String], String]` at the same time. And maybe it's a bad idea to define two endpoints with the same type parameter (just a guess, but something doesn't fit here, it doesn't work with Alexey Romanov's solution either).

**UPDATE**

(1) is solved by making `ReqMarshaller` covariant:

```
trait ReqMarshaller[+ReqImpl <: MyReq[Resp], Resp] { ...
```

(2) still fails with ambiguous implicits.